# How to tell GHC what fromIntegral should do

Tags: haskell

```
data N_ary = N_ary Int String Int deriving Eq
```

stores numbers to various bases. For example 15 to the bases 2, 10, and 16 are `N_ary 1 "1111" 2`, `N_ary 1 "15" 10`, and `N_ary 1 "F" 16` respectively. (The first field is -1, 0, or 1 as a sign.)

I defined an operator `infixl 5 ~>` for converting things into `N_ary` objects and a class for convertible types.

```
class N_aryAble a where
  (~>) :: a -> Int -> N_ary
```

I had no problems with `instance N_aryAble Integer` or `instance N_aryAble N_ary` (to change one base to another), but I ran into a problem with

```
instance N_aryAble Int where
  int ~> base = fromIntegral int ~> base

Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘fromIntegral’
prevents the constraint ‘(Num a0)’ from being solved.
...

Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘~>’
prevents the constraint ‘(N_aryAble a0)’ from being solved.
...
```

Type signatures within instance declarations are not allowed without a special setting.

```
instance N_aryAble Int where
  (~>) :: Int -> Int -> N_ary
  int ~> base = fromIntegral int ~> base

 Illegal type signature in instance declaration:
    (~>) :: Int -> Int -> N_ary
  (Use InstanceSigs to allow this)
```

The following works.

```
instance N_aryAble Int where
  int ~> base = fromIntegral int + (0::Integer) ~> base

> (5::Int) ~> 2  ==> N_ary 1 "101" 2
```

But that seems ugly and *ad hoc*. Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a type annotation to the `fromIntegral` call, so to make it non ambiguous.

```
instance N_aryAble Int where
  int ~> base = (fromIntegral int :: Integer) ~> base
```

Comment: Thanks. Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `TypeApplications`?

Comment: @Alec Yes, that would actually be my first choice. However, in such simple case a type annotation suffices and requires no extensions. Further, here we would need `fromIntegral @ _ @ Integer int` which isn't as convenient, since we need to make explicit the second type argument.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not that the compiler can't deduce *what **from*** to convert the type from. That could be fixed with a signature for that particular instance method, which BTW you could write like

```
instance N_aryAble Int where
  (~>) = (~~>)
   where (~~>) :: Int -> Int -> N_ary
         int ~~> base = fromIntegral int ~> base
```

But that information is already clear from the class method signature, so it won't help you.

No, the problem is that you don't specify what type *to convert **to***, and because the argument to `~>` is again polymorphic the compiler has nothing else to infer it from. This could as well convert `Int` to `Int`, causing an infinite recursion loop because you end up with the same `~>` instantiation you're trying to define!

You can either clarify this with a signature to the result of `fromIntegral` as [shown by chi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40769610/745903), or you can simply use the `to-`-version of the conversion function that's monomorphic with an `Integer` result:

```
instance N_aryAble Int where
  int ~> base = toInteger int ~> base
```